# What is the idiomatic way of using an if-let binding when matching a `Result` and still being able to capture the error?

Tags: rust

```
fn lines_from_file<F>(filename: F) -> Result<io::Lines<BufReader<File>>, io::Error>
where
    F: std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path>,
{
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}

fn main() {
    let filename: &str = "input.pdl";
    // This works fine
    match lines_from_file(filename) {
        Ok(lines) => {
            for line in lines {
                println!("{:?}", line);
            },
        }
        Err(e) => println!("Error {:?}", e),
    }
}
```

I'd like to use this instead:

```
if let lines = Ok(lines_from_file(filename)) {
    for line in lines {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
} else {
    println!("Error {:?}" /*what goes here?*/,)
}
```

But that gives an error:

```
| if let lines = Ok(lines_from_file(filename)) {
|                ^^ cannot infer type for `E`
```

What is the idiomatic way of using an if-let binding when matching a `Result` and still being able to capture the error?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> [...] using an if-let binding when matching a Result and still being able to capture the error?

This is fundamentally impossible with one `if let`. The `if let` construct's only purpose is to make life easier in the case where you only want to destructure one pattern. If you want to destructure both cases of a `Result`, you have to use `match` (or multiple `if let` or `unwrap()`, but this is not a good solution). Why you don't want to use `match` in the first place?

Regarding your compiler error: you added the `Ok()` on the wrong side:

```
if let Ok(lines) = lines_from_file(filename) { ... }
```

This is the correct way of using `if let`: the destructuring pattern to the left, the expression producing a value to the right.

Comment: Ok so `if let Ok(lines) = lines_from_file(filename) {...} else { println!("Error"); }` would be a reasonable approach.

Comment: @Ronnie It would work, but of course, you wouldn't print any information about the error. So I'd recommend you to just use `match` like in your first example.

Comment: Is there an opposite pattern? I generally want to leave error handling nested in the beginning and then proceed knowing that the value is what I expect it to be

Comment: @radrow Not 100% sure what you mean, but you can do `if let Err(e) = ...` for sure. Or use `let Ok(v) = returnsResult() else { /* diverging expr */ }` ([let else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html)).

Comment: Perfect, I needed that `let`-`else` construction exactly. Thanks!