# Concise logging when matching Result

Tags: rust

I am working on a large project in Rust with many moving pieces. One of my agendas is to log an error if something goes wrong in any part so I can debug later.
However, it seems for every function call the conciseness has vanished, plausibly due to my naivete.

How can I make this more concise? I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248583/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-using-an-if-let-binding-when-matching-a-result-an) which essentially asks to use a `match` to capture both  `OK()` and `Err`.

```
fn pathway_1(x: &str, y: &str) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
    let unique_numbers = match query_unique_numbers(&x,  &y) {
        Ok(r) => r
        Err(e) => {
        log::error!(target: "normal", "Could not query unique numbers. Err {e}");
        return None;
        }
    }

    let unique_people = match query_unique_people(&unique_numbers,  &y) {
        Ok(r) => r
        Err(e) => {
        log::error!(target: "normal", "Could not query unique people. Err {e}");
        return None;
        }
    }

    let relevant_things_by_people = match query_relevant_things(&unique_people,  &y) {
        Ok(r) => r
        Err(e) => {
        log::error!(target: "normal", "Could not query relevant things. Err {e}");
        return None;
        }
    }

    /// Many such function calls below.

    Some(vector_of_strings)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.ok()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) to convert a `Result` into an `Option` and then use `?` to propagate it.

Logging on each result could be achieved with [`.map_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) to apply a "transformation" to the error. It may be slightly better to use [`.inspect_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.inspect_err) (when stabilized) or [`.tap_err()`](https://docs.rs/tap/1.0.1/tap/trait.TapFallible.html#tymethod.tap_err) (from the [tap](https://crates.io/crates/tap) crate), though since the error is not used after logging, it doesn't really matter:

```
fn pathway_1(x: &str, y: &str) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
    let unique_numbers = query_unique_numbers(&x, &y)
        .map_err(|e| { log::error!(target: "normal", "Could not query unique numbers. Err {e}"); })
        .ok()?;

    let unique_people = query_unique_people(&unique_numbers, &y)
        .map_err(|e| { log::error!(target: "normal", "Could not query unique people. Err {e}"); })
        .ok()?;

    let relevant_things_by_people = query_relevant_things(&unique_people, &y)
        .map_err(|e| { log::error!(target: "normal", "Could not query relevant things. Err {e}"); })
        .ok()?;

    /// Many such function calls below.

    Some(vector_of_strings)
}
```

---

However, I would not do it like this. You seem to be using `Option` in the return type to indicate failure. If that is the case, you should return a `Result`. And if you do that, you can create a proper encompassing error type that can express what step failed, with what original error, and the display logic (using something like the [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) crate):

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum QueryError {
    #[error("Could not query unique numbers. Err {0}")]
    UniqueNumbers(SomeError),
    #[error("Could not query unique people. Err {0}")]
    UniquePeople(SomeError),
    #[error("Could not query relevant things. Err {0}")]
    RelevantThings(SomeError),
}

fn pathway_1(x: &str, y: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, QueryError> {
    let unique_numbers = query_unique_numbers(&x, &y)
        .map_err(QueryError::UniqueNumbers)?;

    let unique_people = query_unique_people(&unique_numbers, &y)
        .map_err(QueryError::UniquePeople)?;

    let relevant_things_by_people = query_relevant_things(&unique_people, &y)
        .map_err(QueryError::RelevantThings)?;

    /// Many such function calls below.

    Ok(vector_of_strings)
}
```

Then you can handle all errors in one place in the caller. For example:

```
match pathway_1(x, y) {
    Ok(vector_of_strings) => {
        // do something
    }
    Err(e) => {
        log::error!(target: "normal", "{e}");
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a smart way to get around the problem. I appreciate the two ways of doing the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom method on `Result`, `log()`, that logs the error with context:

```rust
trait ResultExt<T> {
    fn log(self, context: &str) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T, E: std::fmt::Display> ResultExt<T> for Result<T, E> {
    fn log(self, context: &str) -> Option<T> {
        match self {
            Ok(v) => Some(v),
            Err(err) => {
                log::error!(target: "normal", "{context}. Err {err}");
                None
            }
        }
    }
}

fn pathway_1(x: &str, y: &str) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
    let unique_numbers = query_unique_numbers(&x, &y).log("Could not query unique numbers")?;

    let unique_people =
        query_unique_people(&unique_numbers, &y).log("Could not query unique people")?;

    let relevant_things_by_people =
        query_relevant_things(&unique_people, &y).log("Could not query relevant things")?;

    /// Many such function calls below.
    Some(vector_of_strings)
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. And we don't have to rely on a library as @kmdreko suggested i.e. `thiserror`.